# Accessing a vector<vector<int>> as a flat array

Tags: c++, vector, std, multidimensional-array, flat

For this array:

```
vector<vector<int> > v;

v.push_back(vector<int>(0));
v.back().push_back(1);
v.back().push_back(2);
v.back().push_back(3);
v.back().push_back(4);
```

I can output {1, 2, 3, 4} easily enough:

```
cout << v[0][0] << endl;
cout << v[0][1] << endl;
cout << v[0][2] << endl;
cout << v[0][3] << endl;
```

To access it as a flat array I can do this:

```
int* z = (int*)&v[0].front();

cout << z[0] << endl;
cout << z[1] << endl;
cout << z[2] << endl;
cout << z[3] << endl;
```

Now, how do I access the multidimensional vector as a flat multidimensional array? I cannot use the same format as accessing a single-dimensional vector:

```
// This does not work (outputs garbage)
int** n = (int**)&v.front();

cout << n[0][0] << endl;
cout << n[0][1] << endl;
cout << n[0][2] << endl;
cout << n[0][3] << endl;
```

The workaround I've found is to do this:

```
int** n = new int* [v.size()];

for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
   n[i] = &v.at(i).front();
}

cout << n[0][0] << endl;
cout << n[0][1] << endl;
cout << n[0][2] << endl;
cout << n[0][3] << endl;
```

Is there a way to access the entire multidimensional vector like a flat c-style array without having to dynamically allocate each dimension above the data before accessing it?

Speed is not critical in the implementation and clarity for maintenance is paramount. A multidimensional vector is just fine for storing the data. However, I want to also expose the data as a flat c-style array in the SDK so that it can be easily accessible by other languages. This means that exposing the vectors as an STL object is a no go.

The solution I came up with works fine for my needs as I only evaluate the array once at the very end of processing to "flatten" it. However, is there a better way to go about this? Or am I already doing it the best way I possibly can without re-implementing my own data structure (overkill since my flatten code is only a few lines).

Thank you for your advice, friends!

Comment: Do you know the second size, I mean is size of all `vector<int>` elements should be the same?

Answer (score 3):

A `vector`'s buffer is in general dynamically allocated.

That means that when you have a `vector` of `vector`s, then regarding the internal buffers you have something akin to an array of pointers, each pointer pointing to an array.

If you need to switch between 1D and 2D views of the same data, the simplest is probably to just define a 2D array class, like this (off the cuff):

```
typedef ptrdiff_t Size;
typedef Size Index;

template< class Item >
class Array2D
{
private:
    std::vector< Item > items_;
    Size                width_;
    Size                height_;

    Index indexFor( Index const x, Index const y )
    { return y*width_ + x; }

public:
    Size width() const { return width_; }
    Size height() const { return height_; }

    Item& operator()( Index const x, Index const y )
    { return items_[indexFor( x, y )]; }

    Item const& operator()( Index const x, Index const y ) const
    { return items_[indexFor( x, y )]M; }

    Size bufferSize() const { return width_*height_; }
    Item* buffer() { return &items_[0]; }
    Item const* buffer() const { return &items_[0]; }

    Array2D( Size const w, Size const h )
        : items_( w*h )
        , width_( w )
        , height_( h )
    {}
};
```

Then you can do things like

```
Array2D< int >  a( 4, 3 );

for( Index y = 0;  y < a.height();  ++y )
{
    for( Index x = 0;  x < a.width();  ++x )
    {
        foo( a( x, y ) );
    }
}
```

*and*

```
Array2D< int >  a( 4, 3 );

int* const pb = a.buffer();
for( Index i = 0;  i < a.bufferSize();  ++i )
{
    foo( pb[i];
}
```

Comment: +1: changed. you *are* doing this column-dominant, figured that out at the very end. totally right either way.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, how do I access the multidimensional vector as a flat multidimensional array?

You can't.

The reason you can access `vector<int>` as an `int[]` is because the layout is the same. The memory layout of `vector<vector<int>>` is different from the layout of `int*[]`, which means you can't access it as though it were `int*[]`.

If you can't avoid accessing the data via a `int*[]` then what you're doing, allocating an array of `int*` and populating it with pointers into the vectors, is the best you can do. It would be better if you could avoid needing to do this in the first place though.

You might want to use an exception safe holder for the `int*[]`. You also probably don't need to use `vector::at()` and you might consider whether you need to handle the case that one of the vector's is empty. Here I address these issues using C++11 features.

```
std::unique_ptr<int*[]> n(new int* [v.size()]);
transform(begin(v), end(v), n.get(), [](std::vector<int> &i) { return i.data(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't because although vectors are guaranteed to store their elements in continuous memory, a vector of vectors doesn't guarantee the same storage layout as a 2D C-style array.

So no, it's not possible, and I'd go even further and say that `int* z = (int*)&v[0].front();` is just plain ugly.

Answer (score 0):

If your 1d vectors (`std::vector<int>`) are of the same size - then keep in vector raw arrays:

```
typedef int ARRAY[6];
std::vector<ARRAY> yourVector;
```

If their size are not identical - then you have real problem, since each `std::vector<int>` occupied contiguous memory area, but these areas are not contiguous. Exactly like in this raw C arrays:

```
int** a = new int*[3];
a[0] = new int[4];
a[1] = new int[5];
```

`a` does not point to contiguous memory of size `(4+5)*sizeof(int)`...